# ¿Es posible mandar a Tag manager diversos valores dentro del DataLayer?

Tags: google-analytics

Actualmente quiero trackear cuando se hace click en un boton y mandar ciertos datos, por el momento lo hago de la siguiente manera, cabe mencionar que el trigger y variable ya las tengo registradas en Google Tag manager:

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
window.dataLayer.push({
‘Id’: ‘01’,
‘event’: ‘click’
});

Pero quisiera saber si se puede enviar datos a traves del dataLayer para verlos en Google analytics junto con el evento.

Answer (score 2):

un dataLayer solo recoge la información, que aunque dinámicamente tu lo veas como pares de parámetros y valores, realmente el valor tiene que ser una variable que tú mismo implementas en el site (o que lo recoge a través de funciones jQuery o JS).

Ahora bien, puedes o bien aumentar el par de parámetros y valores en el dataLayer actual, o ir aumentando el tamaño del mismo a través de Google Tag Manager.

La otra alternativa, sería que directamente creas un dataLayer como **custom HTML** en Tag Manager, como decía anteriormente, y que el evento se encarga de enviarlo a Google Analytics, con una simple línea de código.

```html
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

```
<script>
```

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
window.dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'new_subscriber',
 'formLocation': 'footer'
 });

y para que puedas enviar el todo tendrá que realizar algo así, en una función:

```html
  function checkDatalayer(){
  var DL = window.dataLayer[1];
  if(typeof DL["CONDICION"] != "undefined"){
      if(DL["CONDICION"].length>0){
          var cookie = getCookieData();
          if(typeof(cookie.CookieID == 'undefined')){
              setTimeout(function(){
                  cookie =  getCookieData();
              }, 1600);
          }
          var datos = {
                dispositivo:        getDevice(),
                ruta:               getRuta(), 
                id_cookie:          cookie.CookieID,
                date_visit:         cookie.VisitDate,
                traffic_source:     cookie.Origen,
                nombre_navegador:   getBrowser(),
                version_navegador:  navigator.appVersion,
          };
          //console.log(DL);
          if(DL["CONDICION"] == "2.3" && DL["VisitorStatus"] == "Logged"){
            ga('send', 'event', 'CATEGORY', 'ACTION', 'LABEL', 'VALUE');
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            return true;
```

Creo que depende bien como quieres recolectar el objeto y que más funcionalidades quieres darle, más que nada depende del resultado esperado que quisieras obtener.